# Java: advice about code

Tags: java

This is my code so far. I am a beginner and I cant understand why this doesn't work properly.

My task is to take a number of minutes (2000 to 40000), and to output how many days, hours, minutes it consititutes (e.g 25000 minutes are - 17 days 8 hours 40 minutes).

Additionally, it should show the date it will be if I add 17 days 8 hours 40 minutes  to the date: 01 September 2015. I am not even close to the output (mine is showing 0 days, 6 hours, 50 mins) -

It must look like this:

> There are 17 days, 8 hours , 40 minutes in 25000 minutes. The future
>   date will be 18 september 2015.

Any suggestions?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // 1 minute = 60 seconds
    // 1 hour = 60 x 60 = 3600
    // 1 day = 3600 x 24 = 86400

    int input = 25000;
    int numberOfDays;
    int numberOfHours;
    int numberOfMinutes;

    numberOfDays = input / 86400;
    numberOfHours = (input % 86400) / 3600;
    numberOfMinutes = ((input % 86400) % 3600) / 60;

    System.out.println("Number of days :" + numberOfDays);
    System.out.println("Number of Hours :" + numberOfHours);
    System.out.println("Number of Mins :" + numberOfMinutes);
}
```

Comment: the question is not clear enough

Comment: Voting close. Not at all clear.

Comment: It seems clear to me.

Comment: @dreamfall, notice how `input` is 25000, but your calculation of `numberOfDays` divides by 86400, a number much greater than 25000. That is why `numberOfDays` is 0.Take a look at @chris-k's answer below. Also, think about using variables instead of bare numbers. E.g., assign 3600 the variable name `secondsPerHour`. That will help you see where your logic errors are.

Comment: @Dreamfall Take a look at my solution, the codes are easier than you imagined.

Answer (score 2):

Like said by Chris K :

```
final static int ONE_DAY_IN_MINUTES = 1440;
```

But you have made two other mistakes :

```
numberOfHours = (input % ONE_DAY_IN_MINUTES) / 3600;
```

Why would you divide by 3600?

Let's take an example :

We have an input of `1500` (it represents `1 day : 1 hour : 0 minutes`)

```
= (1500 % 1440)
= 60
```

We know the rest is 60 minutes, the formula to obtain an hour from minutes is :

```
minutes / 60
```

In this case 60/60 = 1 so the correct code is :

```
numberOfHours = (input % ONE_DAY_IN_MINUTES) / 60;
```

---

Same logic for the following :

```
numberOfMinutes = ((input % ONE_DAY_IN_MINUTES) % 60) / 60;
```

Why would you again divide by 60 when the rest obtained with the modulo already gives you the minutes?

```
numberOfMinutes = (input % ONE_DAY_IN_MINUTES) % 60;
```

Comment: Thank You! Was really Helpful!

Comment: yup but i still dont have the reputation.

Comment: @Dreamfall You just need to check the arrow under the question points. :) I don't think you need reputation to do that

Answer (score 1):

Editing from your codes..

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int input = 25000;  //25000 mins
    int numberOfDays = input / (60 * 24);
    int numberOfHours = input % (60 * 24);
    int numberOfMinutes = input % 60

    System.out.println("Number of days :" + numberOfDays);
    System.out.println("Number of Hours :" + numberOfHours);
    System.out.println("Number of Mins :" + numberOfMinutes);
}
```

Since you always add to `1st September 2015`, without the need to handle the extra minutes and seconds. Just add `numberOfDays` to 01 (1st sept).

---

**Explanation:**

- ***numberOfDays*** = Given minutes **divide** number of 24 hours (in minutes)
- ***numberOfHours*** = Given minutes **mod** number of 24 hours (in minutes)
- ***numberOfMinutes*** = Given minutes **mod** 1 hour (in minutes)

Answer (score 0):

Your constants 60, 3600 and 86400 are the number of **seconds** in a minute, hour and day, hence your program computes the equivalent in days, hours and minutes of 25000 **seconds**. You can use 1, 60 and 24*60 instead and it'll compute the equivalent of 25000 minutes.